# Why are level 1 headings the same size as other headings?

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I just created a new react app and installed tailwindcss and antd libraries. For some reason, my header tags are not changing the font. My code is:

```
import { Button } from "antd";

function PageHeader() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex flex-wrap">
        <h1 className="p-5">Hello</h1>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default PageHeader;
```

However, the font size doesn't change at all and is still as small as a

tag.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> All heading elements are completely unstyled by default, and have the same font-size and font-weight as normal text.
>
> The reason for this is two-fold:
>
> It helps you avoid accidentally deviating from your type scale. By
> default, the browsers assigns sizes to headings that don't exist in
> Tailwind's default type scale, and aren't guaranteed to exist in your
> own type scale.
>
> In UI development, headings should often be visually
> de-emphasized. Making headings unstyled by default means any styling
> you apply to headings happens consciously and deliberately.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#headings-are-unstyled

For those who arrive here disappointed that you're not getting the *styles* you expected from heading elements implemented for that purpose, accessibility and usability best practice mandates that you [use headings for structure, not styling](https://www.med.unc.edu/webguide/accessibility/headings/). If all you're after is visual emphasis, use CSS (via [library-provided classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin) or custom classes).